# \raggedcolumns won't work within Exercise environment

Tags: multicol, vertical-spacing, exercises

I am writing a document that has a number of datasets presented in pairs, of different lengths, which I would like to have the same vertical spacing (and thus possibly white space at the bottom of one list). `multicols` with a `\columnbreak` allows for this, but as the columns are of different lengths, `multicols` will vertically justify the list unless `\raggedcolumns` is used.

This works normally (see List1 and List2 in the MWE), but if I try to do the same within an `Exercise` environment (see List3 and List4), `\raggedcolumns` has no effect. Other discussions have suggested solutions like `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}`, `\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}`, and `\addtolength{\baselineskip}{\fill}` to delete the vertical space, all of which have no effect (either placed directly under `\begin{multicols}` or under the `\columnbreak`). I have also seen discussion of using `multicols*` instead of `multicols`, but I get an error stating that "...`multicols*` with in a box does not make sense. Going to balance anyway...".

Is there any way to achieve the vertical spacing of List1/List2 within an `Exercise` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{exercise}

\begin{document}

Outside of `exercise environment':

\begin{multicols}{2}
\raggedcolumns

List1
\begin{enumerate}
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
\end{enumerate}

\columnbreak

List2
\begin{enumerate}
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\bigskip
Inside `exercise' environment:

\begin{Exercise}[title={An exercise},label=ex1]
    
\begin{multicols}{2}
\raggedcolumns

List3
\begin{enumerate}
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
\end{enumerate}

\columnbreak

List4
\begin{enumerate}
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of raggedcolumns within and outside of an Exercise environment.]

Comment: You can put the entire enumerate inside a `\vbox{...}`.  You can put `\vspace*{\fill}` after it.

Comment: This worked! Although as a note to anyone reading, both enumerates have to be in vboxes for the items to line up exactly (otherwise the longer one is squished).

Comment: I was going to suggest you should be using paracol, except that paracol will not work inside Exercise at all (not in outer par mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The environment has made `\itemsep` stretchy. If you remove the stretch, the end of column space can stretch to compensate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{exercise}

\begin{document}

Outside of `exercise environment':

\begin{multicols}{2}
\raggedcolumns

List1
\begin{enumerate}
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
\end{enumerate}

\columnbreak

List2
\begin{enumerate}
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\bigskip
Inside `exercise' environment:

\begin{Exercise}[title={An exercise},label=ex1]
    
  \begin{multicols}{2}
\raggedcolumns

List3
\begin{enumerate}\itemsep=1\itemsep
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
\end{enumerate}

\columnbreak

List4
\begin{enumerate}\itemsep=1\itemsep
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```